# Ebay Browse API ignoring aspect filter

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

For example:

`https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?category_ids=9355&limit=3&filter=sellers:{alba_mobil}&aspect_filter=categoryId=9355,Brand:{Apple},Model:{Apple iPhone 13 Pro}`

API Explorer Ignoring Aspect Filter, response contains no aspect filter errors. I want to filter items brand and model, can you help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDPE6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your url.  You have an = where there should be an :

Yours:
&aspect_filter=categoryId=9355,Brand:{Apple},Model:{Apple iPhone 13 Pro}

Correct:
&aspect_filter=categoryId:9355,Brand:{Apple},Model:{Apple iPhone 13 Pro}